# Using jQuery to hide parent elements based on Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, hide, parent

I am trying to remove the items from printing using .addClass() and .removeClass(). The ul.gform_fields contains the entire section and a title for each area and li.gfield contain the input areas.

The basic idea is to mark them all as hidden on document load (@media print) and then remove the hidden value from any that are selected including the parent container ul item. The end goal is to have items removed and if all the items of one category are removed then remove the category as well.

I can get the list items to work but I can't seem to get the parent UL to toggle visibility.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#gform_print_button").click( function()
        {

            $("ul.gform_fields").each(function () {
                $(this).addClass("noPrint");
            });

            $("input.ginput_quantity").each(function () {
              if (this.value == "")
                $(this).parent().parent().addClass("noPrint");
              else                  
                $(this).parent().parent().parent().removeClass("noPrint");
                $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("noPrint");
            });
        //javascript:window.print();
        }
    ); 
})
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <ul class="gform_fields">
  <li>
    <h4>Cart &amp; Dollies</h4>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <span>Daily Rate</span>
    <span>Quantity</span>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <label for="input_1_31_1">
    </label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_31.1" value="Furniture Dolly" /> 
    <span >Price:</span> 
    <span id="input_1_31">$6.00</span> 
    <input type="hidden" name="input_31.2" id="ginput_base_price_1_31" value="$6.00" /> 
    <span>Quantity:</span> 
    <input type="text" name="input_31.3" value="" id="ginput_quantity_1_31" class="ginput_quantity" size="10"
    tabindex="24" /></div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <label for="input_1_32_1">
    </label>
    <div class="ginput_container">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_32.1" value="Gorilla Cart" class="gform_hidden" /> 
    <span>Price:</span> 
    <span id="input_1_32">$10.00</span> 
    <input type="hidden" name="input_32.2" id="ginput_base_price_1_32" value="$10.00" /> 
    <span>Quantity:</span> 
    <input type="text" name="input_32.3" value="" id="ginput_quantity_1_32" class="ginput_quantity" size="10"
    tabindex="25" /></div>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <label class="gfield_label" for="input_1_33_1">
    </label>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_singleproduct">
    <input type="hidden" name="input_33.1" value="Magliner / Jr." class="gform_hidden" /> 
    <span>Price:</span> 
    <span id="input_1_33">$15.00</span> 
    <input type="hidden" name="input_33.2" id="ginput_base_price_1_33" value="$15.00" /> 
    <span>Quantity:</span> 
    <input type="text" name="input_33.3" value="" id="ginput_quantity_1_33" class="ginput_quantity" size="10"
    tabindex="26" /></div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="">
    <input type="button" id="gform_print_button" class="gform_button button printbtn" value="Print" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zy87g0Lz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you're after something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/mickatron/zy87g0Lz/6/

Try to avoid DOM traversal, actually try to pretend those parent, sibling etc methods don't even exist. Your code will be more readable, modular and slightly faster in most all cases.

I've included some other tips in the answers comments.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // cache selectors that you reuse
  var $gFormFields = $("ul.gform_fields");
  // hide the whole ul on doc load
  $gFormFields.addClass("noPrint");

    var clickHandler = function(){
    $gFormFields.addClass("noPrint");
    // loop all the li's in the gFormFields
    // superior to looping the input as you don't have to use DOM traversal 
    $("li", $gFormFields).each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
      var $inputValue = $("input.ginput_quantity", $this).val();
      if ($inputValue){             
        $gFormFields.removeClass("noPrint");
        $this.removeClass("noPrint");
      }else {           
        $this.addClass("noPrint");
      }
    });
  };

  // Use .on() and .off() for all events. In later version of jQ even delegates have been moved to .on();
  // assigning the handler to a function expression allows you to remove that specific handler with .off().
  $("#gform_print_button").on('click', clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: That is 99% of it... thanks for the tip on traversals. The one thing that remains is I need to have the category (ul.gform_fields) print if any one of the inputs is selected.
in the jsfiddle it seems that the ul element is remaining red or keeping the noPrint class.

Comment: So you want to also show the li's that do not have inputs as children. As in the "Cart & Dollies" & "Daily Rate Quantity" text? You can add classnames to fields with Gravity, right? Maybe give them a classname and then filter that in the js to show if one is found. PS, I added a few more updates to the code, use whichever version you feel comfortable with.

Comment: I must be half asleep - yes I guess the initial <li> child of <ul> is to remain. I missed that in the HTML code.

Comment: thats a good point I can add class names and that would give me more control over the first element.

Comment: yeah if there's more than one category and corresponding title having class names may give you more flexibility in finding the right ones to enable.